# copy data between workbooks using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Goal: Copy every single thing from source sheet to destination sheet including all the formatting, excluding the formulas(copy just the values)

Expected Result: all the hidden columns to remain hidden, all the coloring and grouping of rows should get copied

Actual Result: Only the values are getting copied, no formatting

[The data looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRjUl.png)
Please note that Cell B6 has the formula
Cell B9 = sum(B6:B8)

Code that I have tried:

```
 import openpyxl as xl
 from copy import copy

 t1 = r'C:\Temp\test1.xlsx'
 t2 = r'C:\Temp\test2.xlsx'

 wb1 = xl.load_workbook(t1, read_only=True, keep_links=False, keep_vba=False, data_only=True)
 #source workbook has many other worksheets, so index has been given to pick the right one
 ws1 = wb1.worksheets[7]

 wb2 = xl.load_workbook(t2)
 ws2 = wb2.active

 mr = ws1.max_row
 mc = ws1.max_column

 for i in range(1,mr+1):
 for j in range(1,mc+1):
     c = ws1.cell(row=i, column=j)
     ws2.cell(row=i,column=j).value = c.value
     #if ws2.cell(row=i,column=j).value is not None:
     if c.has_style:
         ws2.cell()._style = copy(c.style)

  wb2.save(t2)
```

**Error message:**  *AttributeError: 'EmptyCell' object has no attribute 'has_style'*

I read some posts where it was mentioned to get rid of 'read_only=True' from load_workbook but even that ended with **warning message**:
*UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed*

Please excuse me on missing any details as I am new to Stackoverflow & programming altogether.
The above code has been copied from stackoverflow itself but as I couldn't ask further questions on any post that's why I had to post my own with concerns.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Read-only mode is all about the data so style isn't really relevant (except for inferring dates and times) and so the `has_style` method isn't supported. EmptyCells are created to fill in the worksheet so that rows  have even lengths.

You might be able to workaround this using the follow code:

```
if hasattr(c, 'style_array') and any(c.style_array):
   c2._style = c.style_array
```

Otherwise the warnings you see are purely informational: some of the extensions to OOXML in the original file will be lost after processing with openpyxl.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, but it didn't work. Though it didn't even fail. The formatting didn't copy.

Comment: Yes, you might have to do some additional processing because of the way styles work. Unless your source file is really big, you're probably best of not using read-only mode but note that copying style arrays between workbooks is likely to fail anyway.